# Does Google still charge if the API request is bad?

Tags: google-api, google-translate

Anyone know if we get still charged for Google Translate API requests if we make a bad API call?

For example if I sent an API request with 100 characters to be translated but I used an invalid language code so got an error, would I still get charged for the 100 characters in the request?

There's nothing specific on the pricing page
https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Google Translate API charges based only on the number of characters sent to it. See https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq#pricing for more details.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen that. looking further into my reporting figures, the figures shown in the graph in the API console are about 50% of that are shown when I download the historical data. Looking into my billing history I'm being charged on the graph, not the historical data figures. My guess is that the historical data includes errors and the graph doesn't. I'll keep looking.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing Google doesn't charge for failed translations, at least for the Advanced methods.